# Unable to connect second org peer to channel in HLF

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

1 I am following below link to setup my first network on Hyperledger Fabric http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html

Whatever steps are mentioned in this setup i am pretty much able to do all.My all docker container working good The issue is than when I try to join other peers of second org. to the channel, using below

"Join peer0.dfarmretail.com to the channel."

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DfarmretailMSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@dfarmretail.com/msp" peer0.dfarmretail.com peer channel join -o orderer.dfarmadmin.com:7050 -b dfarmchannel.block
```

however I am getting below error

```
error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.dfarmretail.com:8051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:8051: connect: connection refused"
```

Please see below files

my Docker-composer.yaml

```
version: '2'

networks:
  dfarm:

services:
  ca.dfarmadmin.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.dfarmadmin.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ad62c9f5133ad87c5f94d6b3175eb059395b5f68caf43e439e6bb7d42d8296e4_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dfarmadmin.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.dfarmadmin.com
    networks:
      - dfarm

  orderer.dfarmadmin.com:
    container_name: orderer.dfarmadmin.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/dfarmadmin.com/orderers/orderer.dfarmadmin.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dfarmadmin.com/peers/peer0.dfarmadmin.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerDfarmadmin
    networks:
      - dfarm

  peer0.dfarmadmin.com:
    container_name: peer0.dfarmadmin.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.dfarmadmin.com
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DfarmadminMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.dfarmadmin.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.dfarmadmin.com:7051
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_dfarm
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dfarmadmin.com/peers/peer0.dfarmadmin.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dfarmadmin.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.dfarmadmin.com
      - couchdb
    networks:
      - dfarm

  peer0.dfarmretail.com:
    container_name: peer0.dfarmretail.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.dfarmretail.com
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DfarmretailMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.dfarmretail.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.dfarmretail.com:8051
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_dfarm
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 8051:8051
      - 8053:8053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dfarmretail.com/peers/peer0.dfarmretail.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/dfarmretail.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.dfarmadmin.com
      - couchdb
    networks:
      - dfarm    

  couchdb:
    container_name: couchdb
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    networks:
      - dfarm


  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.dfarmadmin.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DfarmadminMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/dfarmadmin.com/users/Admin@dfarmadmin.com/msp
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    networks:
        - dfarm
    depends_on:
     - orderer.dfarmadmin.com
     - peer0.dfarmadmin.com
     - peer0.dfarmretail.com
     - couchdb
```

my start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Exit on first error, print all commands.
set -ev

# don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=90 
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d  ca.dfarmadmin.com  orderer.dfarmadmin.com  peer0.dfarmadmin.com  peer0.dfarmretail.com  couchdb

# wait for Hyperledger Fabric to start
# incase of errors when running later commands, issue export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=<larger number>
export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=10
#echo ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}

# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DfarmadminMSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@dfarmadmin.com/msp" peer0.dfarmadmin.com peer channel create -o orderer.dfarmadmin.com:7050 -c dfarmchannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
# Join peer0.dfarmadmin.com to the channel.
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DfarmadminMSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@dfarmadmin.com/msp" peer0.dfarmadmin.com peer channel join -b dfarmchannel.block

# Join peer0.dfarmretail.com to the channel.
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=DfarmretailMSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@dfarmretail.com/msp" peer0.dfarmretail.com peer channel join -o orderer.dfarmadmin.com:7050 -b dfarmchannel.block
```

its my project folder structure.

```
├── config
│   ├── channel.tx
│   ├── DfarmadminMSPanchors.tx
│   ├── DfarmretailMSPanchors.tx
│   └── genesis.block
├── configtx.yaml
├── crypto-config
│   ├── 1
│   ├── ordererOrganizations
│   │   └── dfarmadmin.com
│   │       ├── ca
│   │       │   ├── 5f0077f4811e16e3bac8b64ae22e35bd52f3205538587e0a52eaa49e86b57c4c_sk
│   │       │   └── ca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│   │       ├── msp
│   │       │   ├── admincerts
│   │       │   │   └── Admin@dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│   │       │   ├── cacerts
│   │       │   │   └── ca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│   │       │   └── tlscacerts
│   │       │       └── tlsca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│   │       ├── orderers
│   │       │   └── orderer.dfarmadmin.com
│   │       │       ├── msp
│   │       │       │   ├── admincerts
│   │       │       │   │   └── Admin@dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│   │       │       │   ├── cacerts
│   │       │       │   │   └── ca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│   │       │       │   ├── keystore
│   │       │       │   │   └── ecda7305295e86d0890aea73874c80c21a9b29dc04435ef521f1025194a366c8_sk
│   │       │       │   ├── signcerts
│   │       │       │   │   └── orderer.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│   │       │       │   └── tlscacerts
│   │       │       │       └── tlsca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│   │       │       └── tls
│   │       │           ├── ca.crt
│   │       │           ├── server.crt
│   │       │           └── server.key
│   │       ├── tlsca
│   │       │   ├── 199db47c8e231c6cff329e1fdfa8b522ef7b74847808f61045057b56498f49fd_sk
│   │       │   └── tlsca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│   │       └── users
│   │           └── Admin@dfarmadmin.com
│   │               ├── msp
│   │               │   ├── admincerts
│   │               │   │   └── Admin@dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│   │               │   ├── cacerts
│   │               │   │   └── ca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│   │               │   ├── keystore
│   │               │   │   └── 0c5004c87035e89b735940b5b446d59d138c1af8f42b73980c7d7b03373ee333_sk
│   │               │   ├── signcerts
│   │               │   │   └── Admin@dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│   │               │   └── tlscacerts
│   │               │       └── tlsca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│   │               └── tls
│   │                   ├── ca.crt
│   │                   ├── client.crt
│   │                   └── client.key
│   └── peerOrganizations
│       ├── dfarmadmin.com
│       │   ├── ca
│       │   │   ├── ad62c9f5133ad87c5f94d6b3175eb059395b5f68caf43e439e6bb7d42d8296e4_sk
│       │   │   └── ca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │   ├── msp
│       │   │   ├── admincerts
│       │   │   │   └── Admin@dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │   │   ├── cacerts
│       │   │   │   └── ca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │   │   └── tlscacerts
│       │   │       └── tlsca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │   ├── peers
│       │   │   ├── peer0.dfarmadmin.com
│       │   │   │   ├── msp
│       │   │   │   │   ├── admincerts
│       │   │   │   │   │   └── Admin@dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │   │   │   │   ├── cacerts
│       │   │   │   │   │   └── ca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │   │   │   │   ├── keystore
│       │   │   │   │   │   └── 66f1271392ea3ce4d3548e91ee5620591e79e538e36a69b38786b3f11f3c53e2_sk
│       │   │   │   │   ├── signcerts
│       │   │   │   │   │   └── peer0.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │   │   │   │   └── tlscacerts
│       │   │   │   │       └── tlsca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │   │   │   └── tls
│       │   │   │       ├── ca.crt
│       │   │   │       ├── server.crt
│       │   │   │       └── server.key
│       │   │   └── peer0.dfarmretail.com
│       │   │       └── msp
│       │   │           └── keystore
│       │   ├── tlsca
│       │   │   ├── f6f49b0ff9c7f850e5f655dfbb88ce7b8c07f3f872d151346ac65c6f5f2ef80d_sk
│       │   │   └── tlsca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │   └── users
│       │       ├── Admin@dfarmadmin.com
│       │       │   ├── msp
│       │       │   │   ├── admincerts
│       │       │   │   │   └── Admin@dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │       │   │   ├── cacerts
│       │       │   │   │   └── ca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │       │   │   ├── keystore
│       │       │   │   │   └── 9c65737a78159bf977b9e38299c9c8e02278f76c3d4650caf32a4da845947547_sk
│       │       │   │   ├── signcerts
│       │       │   │   │   └── Admin@dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │       │   │   └── tlscacerts
│       │       │   │       └── tlsca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │       │   └── tls
│       │       │       ├── ca.crt
│       │       │       ├── client.crt
│       │       │       └── client.key
│       │       └── User1@dfarmadmin.com
│       │           ├── msp
│       │           │   ├── admincerts
│       │           │   │   └── User1@dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │           │   ├── cacerts
│       │           │   │   └── ca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │           │   ├── keystore
│       │           │   │   └── 458f1f699493828d88507fabb9ad2dab4fc2cc8acdaf4aa65c1fda12710227dd_sk
│       │           │   ├── signcerts
│       │           │   │   └── User1@dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │           │   └── tlscacerts
│       │           │       └── tlsca.dfarmadmin.com-cert.pem
│       │           └── tls
│       │               ├── ca.crt
│       │               ├── client.crt
│       │               └── client.key
│       └── dfarmretail.com
│           ├── ca
│           │   ├── 8f839598652d94f6ab6cb3d0f15390df5fe8dd7b6bb88c5c3b75205b975bc8d2_sk
│           │   └── ca.dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│           ├── msp
│           │   ├── admincerts
│           │   │   └── Admin@dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│           │   ├── cacerts
│           │   │   └── ca.dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│           │   └── tlscacerts
│           │       └── tlsca.dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│           ├── peers
│           │   └── peer0.dfarmretail.com
│           │       ├── msp
│           │       │   ├── admincerts
│           │       │   │   └── Admin@dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│           │       │   ├── cacerts
│           │       │   │   └── ca.dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│           │       │   ├── keystore
│           │       │   │   └── 2115fb2c52372041918517c2dcef91cb7cc66ca4a987a1606a98e9b75d78ab91_sk
│           │       │   ├── signcerts
│           │       │   │   └── peer0.dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│           │       │   └── tlscacerts
│           │       │       └── tlsca.dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│           │       └── tls
│           │           ├── ca.crt
│           │           ├── server.crt
│           │           └── server.key
│           ├── tlsca
│           │   ├── 8b26e70a303598e0012852426ac93be726210c5911baf4695785cf595bad3041_sk
│           │   └── tlsca.dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│           └── users
│               ├── Admin@dfarmretail.com
│               │   ├── msp
│               │   │   ├── admincerts
│               │   │   │   └── Admin@dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│               │   │   ├── cacerts
│               │   │   │   └── ca.dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│               │   │   ├── keystore
│               │   │   │   └── 7ac01c0d8b0b4f3245d1e68fe34d34a2e1727059c459c1418b68b66870328eb2_sk
│               │   │   ├── signcerts
│               │   │   │   └── Admin@dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│               │   │   └── tlscacerts
│               │   │       └── tlsca.dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│               │   └── tls
│               │       ├── ca.crt
│               │       ├── client.crt
│               │       └── client.key
│               └── User1@dfarmretail.com
│                   ├── msp
│                   │   ├── admincerts
│                   │   │   └── User1@dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│                   │   ├── cacerts
│                   │   │   └── ca.dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│                   │   ├── keystore
│                   │   │   └── e40665832cc9d4fce41f72b04505655f9eb46e3b704547987f03863de37331b5_sk
│                   │   ├── signcerts
│                   │   │   └── User1@dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│                   │   └── tlscacerts
│                   │       └── tlsca.dfarmretail.com-cert.pem
│                   └── tls
│                       ├── ca.crt
│                       ├── client.crt
│                       └── client.key
├── crypto-config.yaml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── generate.sh
├── init.sh
├── README.md
├── start.sh
├── stop.sh
└── teardown.sh
```

docker logs for dfarmretail container 
[image: docker logs for dfarmretail container]

[image]

docker logs orderer.dfarmadmin.com

[image]
 I have tried lot to rectify the issue however I am unable to so could you please help on this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is your peer for `peer0.dfarmretail.com` running OK? (I would check the log for it)  In your docker compose file you are configuring both your peers to use the same CouchDB container - but you need to configure a separate CouchDB for each peer.  The retail peer maybe failing because of some problem with the CouchDB container already being allocated to the admin peer.  The 2nd CouchDB container will have to use a different port, and the retail peer will have to be changed to connect to that new port.

I notice that you are exporting port 7053 on you peer.  Port 7053 was used on 'earlier' versions of Fabric for the eventhub I think - what version of Fabric are you using?

You don't have to use CouchDB for your peers, but if you configure your peers to use CouchDB ( `CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB` ) then you need a separate CouchDB container for each.

**Following updates to the question and comment:**

The original error shows a "connection refused" but from the log it looks like the peer is still running.  So it looks like some networking error - there is also a line in the dfarmretail peer log showing that the chaincode listen address is using port 7052, whereas I think it should have 8052.

I suggest you add these 2 config lines to the dfarmadmin peer in the docker compose file:
      `- CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052`

and for dfarmretail peer:
      `- CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8052`

This should clear any port ambiguation and make the peers listen on all interfaces.

Comment: Thanks@R Thatcher for all explanation. I have remove couchDB instance from dfarmretail and also change the port 7053 to 7052 however still facing error

Answer (score 0):

You could try the free tool from www.chaincoder.org which will generate all config files for you and let you easily code and deploy chaincodes on peers. Follow here [Chaincoder](https://www.chaincoder.org)